# Sick Hibiscus Plant

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, aphids

I’ve had this hibiscus for 1 year it was beautiful and healthy and then it had gotten aphids. I had treated it for the aphids and things seemed to improve. But now it’s in such poor condition I’m not sure I can save it.

Its leaves have done everything from turning yellow to curling up and now they’re transparent. I fought so hard to get rid of the aphids that I’m beyond frustrated with this plant. Things I’ve tried to correct the situation: changing sunlight to more and less sunny spots, giving it more and less water, changing soil, fertilizing it every month (each packet is premade so I don’t need to mix anything so I know it’s mixed correctly) I have it outside now that the weather is nice hoping that will help improve the situation. Please help I’m going to lose my mind with this plant.

[image: Image of Leaf]

Answer (score 1):

If you've done everything you mentionned in the same year, it's likely suffering from overwork: too many changes and too much fertilizer. It needs some calm conditions in order to make a comeback. Just keep the soil slightly moist—not wet, not dry— and place it in a very bright place where you won't have to move it for a year, with either dappled sunlight or no more than two hours direct sunlight on it, and wait a full year before taking any other action.

Next time one of your plants gets aphids, try to put a ladybug on the plant, or rub some neem oil carefully all over the plant with your fingers to get into small textures. It'll look sticky for a few weeks but it will be cured of many things.